# How to execute a .py file with a class using .robot file or integrating it to robot framework?

Tags: python, automation, robotframework, desktop-application, pywinauto

I need to execute the below code using robot framework .robot file help me to create keywords and other necessary steps

```
#launch_app.py


from pywinauto.timings import TimeoutError, wait_until
from pywinauto import application
from config import detransitPath
import time

app = None


class LaunchApp:

    def __init__(self,detransitPath):
        self.detransitPath = detransitPath
        
    def launchApp(self):
        global app
        app = application.Application(backend="uia").start(self.detransitPath)
        #wait_until(timeout=10, retry_interval=0.7, func=lambda: signinWindow.exists())

        from locators import signinWindow, signinButton, transitUI
        signinWindow.print_control_identifiers(depth=10)
        wait_until(timeout=10, retry_interval=0.7, func=lambda: signinWindow.exists())
        signinButton.click_input()
        
        wait_until(timeout=17, retry_interval=0.7, func=lambda: transitUI.exists())
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you have tried so far and share your Robot Framework script? There is a plenty of information in the [Robot Framework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries) for you to get started.

Comment: class name and filename holding it should be same - renaming the file is probably easier. After that you should be able to just load that file with  ```Library     LaunchApp.py``` and you should have "launchapp" keyword.